# Order by problem caused by the '_' character

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm using MSSQL Server 2019 and I've some data like;

```
|    FileName    |
|----------------|
| DummyData._0   |
| DummyData._1   |
| DummyData._10  |
| DummyData._100 |
| DummyData._101 |
| DummyData._102 |
| DummyData._11  |
| DummyData._2   |
| DummyData._20  |
| DummyData_r1_21|
```

and I'm trying to get;

```
|    FileName    |
|----------------|
| DummyData._0   |
| DummyData._1   |
| DummyData._2   |
| DummyData._10  |
| DummyData._11  |
| DummyData._20  |
| DummyData._100 |
| DummyData._101 |
| DummyData._102 |
| DummyData_r1_21|
```

and this not worked for me;

```
SELECT FileID, FileName
FROM dbo.demo
ORDER BY
CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FileName), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(FileName)) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(FileName)) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(FileName)) - 1)) AS INT);
```

Comment: Not sure what logic you are using here,  should `DummyData_r1_21` not come after `DummyData._20`

Comment: @M.Ali I'm assuming OP has more data with `_r#` in it and probably wants them sorted by the `r#` before sorting by the number in the suffix. I'm assuming the `r` in this case is a revision #. E.g. the sort order should be `DummyData._20` then `DummyData_r1_21` then `DummyData_r1_22` then `DummyData_r2_19` then `DummyData_r2_20` etc.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. Should have been '_r1._21' and 'DummyData_r1._21' is a different file part and it has more part like _r1._22, _r1._23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT D.FileID, D.[FileName]
FROM dbo.demo D
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('._', D.[FileName]))) P (Pos)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
        (
            LEFT(D.[FileName], P.Pos -1)
            ,RIGHT('00' + SUBSTRING(D.[FileName], P.Pos +2, 255), 3)
        )
    ) X (FilePart, FileOrder)
ORDER BY X.FilePart, X.FileOrder;
```